# Import sources within a group must be alphabetized (TS)

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, codacy

I have import sources in my ts file

Here is it

```
import accounting from "accounting";
import { Feature } from "geojson";
import { GeoJsonProperties } from "geojson";
import { GeoJSONGeometry } from "mapbox-gl";
import Helpers from "../../common/helpers";
import { Layer } from "mapbox-gl";
import mapboxgl from "mapbox-gl";
import { Map } from "mapbox-gl";
import { Popup } from "mapbox-gl";
import { __ } from "../../common/translation";
```

But I have error in codacy

Import sources within a group must be alphabetized

I cannot understand why, because all already alphabetized?

How I can fix this?

Comment: You could also run `tslint --fix --project .` it will reorder the imports alphabetically.

Answer (score 3):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50875684/import-sources-within-a-group-must-be-alphabetized):

> The filepaths are also used as part of the ordering...

These are the 'sources' being referenced in the error. You can disable this in your `tslint.json` file with the following rule:

`"ordered-imports": false`